# Prove $\binom{n}{k+1} = \binom{n}{k} \times \frac{n-k}{k+1}$ using combinatorial arguments.

Tags: combinatorics

I know that the proof is trivial when we look at it algebraically/mathematically.

$$\binom{n}{k+1} = \frac{n!}{(n-k-1)!(k+1)!} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\times \frac{n-k}{k+1} = \binom{n}{k} \times \frac{n-k}{k+1}$$

**Could you please give a proof using combinatorial arguments.**

For example, I tried along the following line of thinking:

$\binom{n}{k+1}$ is the number of ways to choose $k+1$ elements from a set of $n$ elements. I can do this by first choosing $k$ elements in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways and choose one more element from the remaining $n-k$ elements, which is $n-k$ ways. Therefore the number of ways to choose $k+1$ elements is $\binom{n}{k} \times (n-k)$. However this is obviously wrong. But I don't understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: the reason your argument fails is that choosing (say) 1, 2, 3, then 4 as the "one more element" gives the same subset as choosing 1, 2, 4, then 3 as the "one more element". To fix your argument you need to compensate for this overcounting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You split a set of $k+1$ elements into two sets, one having $k$ elements and the other one having one element. In how many ways can you do this split?